# CameraX and barcodes scanning in java

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I'm trying to use `CameraX` and `MlKit` to read barcodes but I get the following error when I try to build my app :

Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

Does anyone know where this problem could come from and how to solve it?

And could anyone tell me where I could find a comprehensive `CameraX` doc using Java and not Kotlin?

Comment: ML Kit demo has sample of using CameraX to scan barcode.
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/CameraXLivePreviewActivity.kt#L307

Answer (score 0):

> Check out this site for the java coding of camerax:
> https://learntodroid.com/how-to-create-a-qr-code-scanner-app-in-android/.
> I use ML-Kit instead of zxing and it works well.

Comment: Replaced my code by yours but the compilation error is still there...

Comment: Is there a mix of Kotlin classes and Java classes? Check the build.gradle file of your project.

Comment: Programming in Java. How could Kotlin class appear?

Comment: Yes, you can mix Java and Kotlin classes!